Random freeze and Bluetooth misconfiguration on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm experiencing random freezes and Bluetooth misconfiguration on Ubuntu 22.04. I hope you can help me out with these logs. I'm feeling pretty frustrated. I don't know if it’s due to my GUI (GNOME) or something else, plus my AirPods Pro 1 aren’t pairing with my machine. I followed a YouTube video to configure my AirPods and Bluetooth, but I ended up messing it up. I’m going to drop some logs I gathered right after the last freeze.

